# Fetch products from main category through API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I am having a main category which has about 10 subcategories that include about 1000 products. Please note that this category is an anchor and its products are inherited from its subcategories. I am using the following code to fetch all the products inside that category, but I only get about 300 (which are assigned to the specific category, leftovers from before the category changed to anchor).

How can I make my API call to fetch all the SKUs of the products in the subcategories as well?

```
$productList = $mclient->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', 279);
foreach($productList as $product){
    $catProducts[] = array('catalog_product.info', $product['product_id']);
}
$result = $mclient->multiCall($session, $catProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve what I want by looping through every subcategory and fetching its products. Here is the code if anyone might need it in the future:

```
$category_tree = $mclient->call($session, 'catalog_category.tree', 279);
foreach($category_tree['children'] as $category){
    foreach($category['children'] as $child_cat){
        $productList = array_merge($mclient->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', $child_cat['category_id']), $productList);
    }
}
foreach($productList as $product){
    $catProducts[] = array('catalog_product.info', $product['product_id']);
}
$result = $mclient->multiCall($session, $catProducts);
```